# The mechanism of obtaining one of the resource files

Tags: c#

Maybe I came up with nonsense but I wonder such a decision.
There are several resource files in library-project Resources:

```
   Resources.File1
   Resources.File2
   Resources.File3
```

I add a class to the Resources project:

```
   public static class Foo {
      static ? GetResource(Object obj) {
         switch (obj) {
            case obj.1: { return Resources.File1; }
            case obj.2: { return Resources.File2; }            
            case obj.3: { return Resources.File3; }
        }
    }
```

Of course what I have written is completely wrong, but I think it's obvious what I want to do.

Comment: I don't quite understand your `obj` parameter and the associated switch block. For instance, what concrete argument would one have to pass in order to get back the `...File1` resource?

Answer (score 2):

The auto-generated `Resources` class exposes its underlying `ResourceManager`. You can simply use it manually:

```
var data = Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("File" + n);
```

Make sure to use the appropriate function: `GetString`, `GetStream` etc.